# Serialize node with different child nodes from DTO objects

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I am using c# and the XmlSerialiser class to create xml from DTO Objects.

Now I have to generate such xml text:

```
<Order>
    <OrderNo>123456</OrderNo>
    <Positions>
        <TextPosition>
            <Text>This is Order No 123456</Text>
        </TextPosition>
        <ItemPosition>
            <ItemId>14789</ItemId>
            <ItemName>Product 1</ItemName>
        </ItemPosition>
        </TextPosition>
        <ItemPosition>
            <ItemId>456</ItemId>
            <ItemName>Product 2</ItemName>
        </ItemPosition>
        <TextPosition>
            <Text>Good bye</Text>
        </TextPosition>
        <SumPosition>
            <Value>123.45 USD</Value>
        </SumPosition>
    </Positions>
</Order>
```

I use Attributes to decorate my classes and everything works fine.
One thing I couldn't solve yet. I need to generate a tag `Positions` with different tag `TextPosition, ItemPosition, ValuePosition, ...` inside.

How do I achive this in c#?

Currently my class Order contains a

```
[XmlElement("Positions")]
public PositionList Positions { get; set; }
```

PositionList is a class with

```
public class PositionList
{
    [XmlElement("Positions")]
    public List<Object> Positions { get; set; }
}
```

In order to avoid a InvalidOperationException I added

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Textposition))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ItemPosition))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(SumPosition))]
```

to my Order class.

However, instead of generating

```
<Positions>
    <TextPosition>...</TextPosition>
</Positions>
```

the serializer generates:

```
<Position d4p1:type="TextPosition" xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">...</Position>
```

The thing is, In don't need to deserialize it my self but provide a XML-file in a very strict format for one customer. Is there a way to achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way:

```
public class Order
{
   public List<BasePosition> Positions { get; set; }
   public Order() { Positions = new List<BasePosition>(); }
}

public class BasePosition
{

}

public class TextPosition : BasePosition
{
   public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class ItemPosition : BasePosition
{
   public int ItemId { get; set; }
   public string ItemName { get; set; }
}

public class SumPosition : BasePosition
{
   public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Example serializing it to an XML file:

```
Order o = new Order();
o.Positions.Add(new TextPosition() { Text = "This is Order No 123456" });
o.Positions.Add(new ItemPosition() { ItemId = 14789, ItemName = "Product 1" });
o.Positions.Add(new TextPosition());
o.Positions.Add(new ItemPosition() { ItemId = 456, ItemName = "Product 2" });
o.Positions.Add(new SumPosition() { Value = "123.45 USB" });
XmlAttributeOverrides specific_attributes = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
XmlAttributes attrs = new XmlAttributes();
attrs.XmlElements.Add(new XmlElementAttribute(typeof(TextPosition)));
attrs.XmlElements.Add(new XmlElementAttribute(typeof(ItemPosition)));
attrs.XmlElements.Add(new XmlElementAttribute(typeof(SumPosition)));
specific_attributes.Add(typeof(Order), "Positions", attrs);
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Order), specific_attributes);

using(MemoryStream mem_stream = new MemoryStream())
{
   ser.Serialize(mem_stream, o);
   using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream("orders.xml", FileMode.Create)))
   {
      bw.Write(mem_stream.ToArray());
   }
}
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Order xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <TextPosition>
    <Text>This is Order No 123456</Text>
  </TextPosition>
  <ItemPosition>
    <ItemId>14789</ItemId>
    <ItemName>Product 1</ItemName>
  </ItemPosition>
  <TextPosition />
  <ItemPosition>
    <ItemId>456</ItemId>
    <ItemName>Product 2</ItemName>
  </ItemPosition>
  <SumPosition>
    <Value>123.45 USB</Value>
  </SumPosition>
</Order>
```

Comment: Awesome! I added a helper class PositionList with one property `public List<Position> Positions {get;set;}` to get an extra `<Positions>` tag between order and the positions, but yes, that did the trick. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help, sorry I missed the extra tag :)

Answer (score 1):

When you need XML in a a very strict format, using a serializer might not be the best option. With a serializer you give up control for convenience, and right now you are fighting to get that control back.

Consider using Linq to XML, the XDocument class.

```
var doc = 
    new XElement("Order", 
      new XElement ("OrderNo", 123456),
      new XElement ("Positions", 
         myPositions.Select(p => new XElement("Position", .... ) ) );
```

Comment: "You give up control for convenience, and right now you are fighting to get that control back." That is very well-stated.

Comment: `You give up control for convenience, and right now you are fighting to get that control back` I don't agree with this one. The AOP approach with Attributes and XmlSerializer is very powerfull and using the `XmlAttributeOverrides` I am able to produce the result I need. Since the DTO classes live in another dll than the serializer, I am able to apply updates in the future without changing the logic itself. Anyway +1 for the XDocument approach, looks promising (maybe I consider using it for another task in the future).